# React js pass data to a component and keep it after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In REACTJS :
Let's say we have a component where i choose an option and the result is shown in an other component BUT in order to see this last component, we have to browse to it.. And of course after refreshing the page i loose the option. How can i keep the information and browse to an other component and see it.

Example: component in the exact path ="/" we put in an  "hello Test" and it is injected (props) in a second component that has the exact path="/data"  to console log it.